# Connection is established, but unable to retrieve message payload on paho mqtt client

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto

My client is unable to receive message payload from the MQTT server. I had set mosquitto on my PC to act as both the server and publisher and execute the following command:

```
mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.2 -t topic/test -m "testing" -i simulator -d
```

Subscribing myself works and payload is received.

However, my client which is using paho mqtt only received successful connection without the payload message. So i have the following code here:

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("connection ok")
    client.subscribe("topic/test")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print("Message received! " + str(msg.payload))
    
    if msg.payload == "testing":
        print("Message received")
        # Do something
        ...

def main():
    #MQTT 
    broker = "192.168.1.2"  #broker ip
    client = mqtt.Client("simulator") 
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message

    client.connect(broker, 1883, 60)
    client.loop_start() 

    while(1):
        ...
```

So it did managed to print "connection ok", but not "Messaged received! ..."

Comment: What happens if you remove the `while(1):` loop and swap `client.loop_start()` for `client,loop_forever()`?

Comment: My sensor modules would stop working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same `client-id` (`simulator`) with `mosquitto_pub` and in your python. As per [the spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc384800405):

> If the ClientId represents a Client already connected to the Server then the Server MUST disconnect the existing Client

So what is happening is:

- Python client connects and subscribes.
- `mosquitto_pub` connects, broker disconnects python client.
- `mosquitto_pub` publishes the message (but as nothing is subscribed the QOS 0 message will be dropped by the broker).
- Python client reconnects and subscribes again.

Try using a different client-id with `mosquitto_pub` (your code works fine when I test it in that way - added a `time.sleep(1)` in the `while(1)`).